# need help rewriting this arcsin function

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

How can I express the following function as $y$ as a function of $a$ and $x$? $$2\arcsin \left (\frac{\frac{x}{2}}{\frac{x^2}{8y}+\frac{y}{2}}\right )\cdot\frac{x^2}{8y}+\frac{y}{2}=ax$$
Reason for asking is: friends and I were laying a laminate floor and discussed how bad it would be if we left no room around the edge and the floor expanded a few %, my thesis was and is: pretty bad. But I'd love to be able to express how bad.

I approximated the problem by disregarding 2 of the four walls and looking at a cross section of bulging floor. I then decided that it looks somewhat similar to a section of a circle (although in hind-sight a parabola might be more accurate). I know the distance between the walls $x$ and the expansion factor $a$ which will give me the length of the floor after it has bulged: $ax$. I'm interested in the height of the bulge in the middle of the room $y$.

Now I need to rewrite the above function that I obtained by performing more steps than I care to write out (unless people here want to know) in order to get an expression for $y$ that depends only on $a$ and $x$. But I'm stuck on the arcsin, I can't figure out how to get all terms with $x$ and $a$ to one side and $y$ to the other.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You mean $y(a,x)=2{\left(\dfrac{x^2}{8y}+\dfrac{y}{2}\right)}\arcsin \left (\dfrac{\frac{x}{2}}{\dfrac{x^2}{8y}+\dfrac{y}{2}}\right )=ax$?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but it looks to me like $y(a,x)$ is dependent upon itself. I was hoping to find an expression for y that does not depend upon $y$, and instead only on $x$ and $a$.

Answer (score 2):

In the same spirit as @Narasimham, for small values of $t$, the simplest Padé approximant is
$$\sin ^{-1}(t)=\frac{6 t}{6-t^2}$$ whose error is $\frac{17 }{360}t^5$.

Just to give an idea
$$I(a)=\int_{-a}^{+a} \Bigg[\sin ^{-1}(t)-\frac{6 t}{6-t^2} \Bigg]^2\,dt$$ some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & I(a) \\
 1.0 & 6.083 \times 10^{-3} \\
 0.9 & 6.818 \times 10^{-4} \\
 0.8 & 1.135 \times 10^{-4} \\
 0.7 & 1.854 \times 10^{-5} \\
 0.6 & 2.634 \times 10^{-6} \\
 0.5 & 2.919 \times 10^{-7}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using
$$t=\frac{4 x y}{x^2+4 y^2}$$
$$2{\left(\frac{x^2}{8y}+\frac{y}{2}\right)}\arcsin \left (\frac{\frac{x}{2}}{\frac{x^2}{8y}+\frac{y}{2}}\right )\sim \frac{3 x \left(x^2+4\right) y^2 \left(x^2+4 y^2\right)}{3 x^4+16 x^2 y^2+48 y^4}$$ leads to a quadratic equation in $z=y^2$
$$12  \left(x^2+4(1-a)\right)z^2+x^2  \left(3 \left(x^2+4\right)-16
   a\right)z-3 a x^4=0$$

**Edit**

It is possible to improve the approximation minimizin with respect to $k$

$$\Phi(k)=\int_{-1}^{+1} \Bigg[\sin ^{-1}(t)-\frac{ t}{1-k~t^2} \Bigg]^2\,dt$$  which is analytic (the longish expression will not be reported here).
Using $k=\sin^2(t)$, the optimum value corresponds to the solution of
$$\sin ^5(t) (2 \pi  \cos (t)-5)+\sin ^3(t) ((5-2 \pi ) \cos (t)+8)+3 (\cos (t)+1)
   \cos ^5(t) \tanh ^{-1}(\sin (t))-\sin (t) (\cos (t)+1) \left(4 \pi  \cos ^5(t)
   \log \left(\frac{2}{\sec (t)+1}\right)+3\right)=0$$ which, numerically, is
$$k_{\text{opt}}=0.258134535583254629273188966092605183439\cdots$$ This number is not identified by inverse symbolic calculators.

The norm  decreased by a factor of $5.35$ and the maximum error by a factor of $3$.

A good approximation
$$t_{\text{opt}}=\frac{19 \pi ^2+411 \pi+402}{741 \pi ^2-1119 \pi-269 }$$ gives the first $20$ significant figures for $k_{\text{opt}}$.

Comment: This looks very impressive! I'm going to need a while to partially understand what you are doing and why. I have never heard of a pade approximant, I don't really understand why you picked 

$$t=\frac{4xy}{x^2+4y^2}$$

as a value for t

And the things you added in your edit are a bit beyond my ability to understand without diving into my books for help haha.

But thank you tremendously for taking the time to work through my problem, in time I might be able to use your solution :).

Answer (score 1):

If
$$\dfrac{x}{2}<<{\left(\frac{x^2}{8y}+\frac{y}{2}\right)} $$

then the slope of sine curve tends to a constant $a=1$ near x=0,

$$y(a,x)=2{\left(\frac{x^2}{8y}+\frac{y}{2}\right)}\arcsin \left (\frac{\frac{x}{2}}{\frac{x^2}{8y}+\frac{y}{2}}\right )\approx x$$

[Arcsin series expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105024/finding-the-power-series-of-arcsin-x)

We can expand $2u \sin^{} \dfrac{x/2}{u} $when $ u={\left(\dfrac{x^2}{8y}+\dfrac{y}{2}\right)} $

using power series to any desired accuracy and numerically evaluate implicit polynomials.

Comment: In my toy example that I use to check if I'm going wrong somewhere, I use x=8, y=2 and a is somewhere between 1.1 and 1.3. So 

$$ \frac{x}{2} </< (\frac{x^2}{8y} + \frac{y}{2}) $$

for very small values of $y$ this is true, but my hypothesis is that with an expansion of the flooring of only a few % $y$ will grow to extreme proportions very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

*I prefer to add a separate answer.*

Using $t=\frac{4 x y}{x^2+4 y^2}$, the problem is to solve for $t$ the equation
$$\frac{\sin ^{-1}(t)}{t}=a$$

Expanding the lhs as a series around $t=0$ and using series reversion

$$t=b+\frac 3{40}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\alpha_n \,b^{2n+1} \qquad \text{with} \qquad b= \sqrt{6(a-1)}$$

The first coefficients $\alpha_n$ make the sequence
$$\left\{3,\frac{323}{560},\frac{21197}{201600},\frac{1030999}{55193600},\frac{1407584257}{430510080000},\frac{409960705481}{723256934400000},\cdots\right\}$$

For a quite severe test, trying for $a=\frac 43$, that is to say $b=\sqrt 2$, we have for the above truncated series
$$t=\frac{102045347517601}{75339264000000 \sqrt{2}}=0.957760$$ while the solution is $0.956774$.

When $t$ is known, then, for a given $x$, $y$ is known.