# Probabilistic or Statistical Interepretation of Central Binomial Identity

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, permutations, combinations

What is probabilistic or statistical interpretation of the identity given below? 
\begin{equation}\label{BIIntro1}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}=4^{n}
\end{equation}

Comment: The combinatorial interpretation is given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/688370 and here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/360780. Following the last link, $\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}/4^{n}$ is the conditional probability, given that there are more heads than tails in $2n+1$ throws of fair coin, that the longest prefix which containes equal number of heads and tails, has length exactly $2k$.

Comment: @NCh Thank you very much for your response. Could you please explain conditional probability approach, this is not clear to me.

Comment: In the linked answer, there proved that if we have word of length $2n+1$ from the alphabet $\{A,B\}$, then the total number of words which containes more letters $A$ than $B$, equals to $4^n=2^2n$. This is one half of total number of words $2^{2n+1}$. Let an event $X$ is that there are more $A$ than $B$ in a word of length $2n+1$ where each letter is chosen independently at random from the alphabet $\{A,B\}$. If we conditioned that this event happens, we consider only words from $X$ as the elementary events. Let $Y_k$ be an event that the longest prefix of a random ...

Comment: ...word which containes as many $A$ as $B$, has length $2k$. In the linked answer it is proved that the number of words in $X\cap Y_k$ equals to $\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}$. Then $$P(Y_k\mid X) =\frac{|X\cap Y_k|}{|X|}=\frac{\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}}{4^n}.$$
The coin looks more convinient to me. Simply replace $A$ by heads and $B$ by tails.

Comment: @NCh Thank you very much for your quick reply. Are these letters are only combinations of letter A and B? For example ABBBBABAA, AAAABAAAB etc. ?

Comment: @NCh Is any statistical interpretation for this identity is possible? If yes, please share with me I shall be highly thankful for this help.

Comment: Not sure that I understood yuor question correctly. Say, for $n=2$, $2n+1=5$, there are $32$ words total. Among them there are $16$ words where more $A$ than $B$: $AAAAA$, $AAABB$, $ABABA$, $BAAAA$ and so on. Then $|X|=4^n=16$. If $k=0$, the event $Y_0=\{AAAAA, AAABB, \ldots\}$ has the probability $P(Y_0\mid X)=\binom00\binom42/16=6/16$. $Y_0$ means that no prefix containes equal number of $A$ and $B$. Next, $Y_1=\{ABAAB, BAAAB, \ldots\}$ - prefix of max length $2$ contains equal number $A$ and $B$. $P(Y_1\mid X)=\binom21\binom{4-2}{2-1}=4/16$ too. And so on.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know what statistical interpretation is possible.

Comment: @NCh Thank you very much for your response.