# Prove $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2k}{k}\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}=4^n$

Tags: generating-functions

My approach: change $4^n$ to $2^{2n}$, then we're trying to show $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2k}{k}\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k}$, but then I got stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See e.g. [Identity for convolution of central binomial coefficients: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{2k}{k}\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}=2^{2n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37971/identity-for-convolution-of-central-binomial-coefficients-sum-limits-k-0n) or  [Proving $\sum_{k=0}^n{2k\choose k}{2n-2k\choose n-k}=4^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687221/proving-sum-k-0n2k-choose-k2n-2k-choose-n-k-4n).

Comment: Oh. Sorry for the duplicate. I couldn't find another one.