# Chu-Vandermonde-like combinatorial identity

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I am looking for a simple combinatorial proof of the binomial identity:
$$\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{2j}{j}\binom{2n-2j}{n-j} = 4^n.\tag{1}$$

---

The standard way I know is to exploit the generating function:
$$\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\binom{2j}{j}x^j = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}},$$
but I wonder if a simple combinatorial explanation of $(1)$ is known.

Comment: I found the answer I was looking for just here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37971/identity-for-convolution-of-central-binomial-coefficients?rq=1.