# Evaluate $1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1\cdot 3}{3\cdot 6}+\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{3\cdot 6\cdot 9}+\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1\cdot 3}{3\cdot 6}+\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{3\cdot 6\cdot 9}+\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7}{3\cdot 6\cdot 9\cdot 12}+\dots$$

How do I proceed on evaluating this sum.

Comment: Make the connection with the Taylor development of $1/\sqrt{1-x}$.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1692678/prove-that-1-frac13-frac1-cdot-33-cdot-6-frac1-cdot-3-cdot-53-cdo. I can't write it in comment. So I'm posting in answer.