# Showing classic combinatorial $4^n$ identity using Vandermonde - What goes wrong?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Show $\sum_{k=0}^{n} {2k \choose k}{2(n-k) \choose n-k} = 4^n$.

I use the fact ${2n \choose n} = (-4)^n {- \frac{1}{2} \choose n} = (4)^n {n- \frac{1}{2} \choose n}$ to reduce the sum to $4^n \sum_{k=0}^{n} {k- \frac{1}{2} \choose k} {n-k- \frac{1}{2} \choose n-k}$ which is equal to $4^n {n-1 \choose n}$ using vandermonde's identity which states ${a+b \choose n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {a \choose k}{b \choose n-k}$.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identity for convolution of central binomial coefficients: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{2k}{k}\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}=2^{2n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37971/identity-for-convolution-of-central-binomial-coefficients-sum-limits-k-0n) See also the linked questions there.

Comment: I see that I could have just kept the $-\frac{1}{2} \choose n$ terms and ended there but I am still not sure where I went wrong here. I think $(-1)^n \binom{-1/2}{n} = \binom{n - 1/2}{n}$ is correct

Comment: Apply Vandermonde at the $(-4)^n \binom{-1/2}{n}$ step instead. (Because we don't want dependence on $k$ in the top argument when applying Vandermonde.)

Comment: Yeah I think you are right, it's probably because of the $k$ on the top argument. Maybe you can post your answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to avoid $k$ in the top argument when using Vandermonde. (See counterexample below.)

Hence if we do, then
$$ \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{2k}{k} \binom{2(n - k)}{n - k} = \sum_{k = 0}^n (-4)^k \binom{-1/2}{k} (-4)^{n - k} \binom{-1/2}{n - k} = (-4)^n \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{-1/2}{k} \binom{-1/2}{n - k},$$
we get, from Vandermonde,
$$ \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{2k}{k} \binom{2(n - k)}{n - k}= (-4)^n \binom{-1}{n} = (-4)^n (-1)^n = 4^n. $$

---

Note on having $k$ in the top argument: consider the trivial example
$$ \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{k}{k} \binom{n - k}{n - k} = n + 1; $$
attempting to apply Vandermonde here would suggest it is equal to $\binom{n}{n} = 1$.

Comment: @amWhy I know the same identity was derived elsewhere---I linked a dupe myself above. I answered because OP had a question about this particular approach, not about any other derivation.

Comment: Thanks for the added info, @prets.  I'll delete my first comment! I made mini-edits to enable me to change my vote, as well.

Comment: No worries @amWhy. In hindsight the question could maybe be improved by being renamed, since it's really a question about Vandermonde's identity (and how using it carelessly is dangerous), not about the combinatorial identity.

Comment: I agree.  And thanks for understanding. ;D