# Seeking combinatorial proof for an Identity involving $2^{2n}$ and a sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

The following identity can be proved us generating functions and Newton's Binomial Theorem
\begin{equation*}
        2^{2n} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{2k}{k} \binom{2n-2k}{n-k},
        \qquad
        \text{for all $n \in \mathbb N$}
\end{equation*}
I have tried to get a combinatorial proof without success.

Does any one know such a proof?

Comment: Here you go: [Identity for convolution of central binomial coefficients: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{2k}{k}\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}=2^{2n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37971/identity-for-convolution-of-central-binomial-coefficients-sum-limits-k-0n)